# Is it possible to compile without MySqlConnector installed?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector

I'm developing an application that uses a MySql connection for Entity Framework 5. Building the solution works on my machine.

Running the application on a machine without MySQLConnector installed also works because I added the following to my app.config file:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
         invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
         description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

But other programmers who just want to compile and run my solution, get the following error on the .edmx file:

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or
>   is not valid.

Is it possible to compile a project that uses MySql with EntityFramework 5, but without the MySqlConnector installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and I've just found a solution for it if you don't want to install MySqlConnector everywhere

Open the edmx file in text mode and look at the Designer section in it.
You should have a ValidateOnBuild property set to True.
Set it to false and you will not have the error displayed when you build.

```
<Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    [...] 
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="False" />
        [...]
```

The same option is availabre in the property window when the diagram is opened.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think  No No . But surely I don't know... you can wait for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `MySql.Data.dll` and `MySql.Data.Entity.dll` available on each machine, since the build is dependent on them.  They can either be registered in the OS, or simply placed in the path for the build to find them.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638456/entity-framework-5-0-code-first-with-mysql-in-wpf) for a related question.

Comment: I already link to this dll and added it to our source control system, but it doesn't seem to be enough for compiling the .edmx file.

Comment: Same issue: adding a reference to both MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.dll is not enough to be able to build the solution on a machine without MySql Connector installed.

Comment: @AnthonyBrien: Perhaps try adding it to the GAC as in the linked question: `gacutil /i path_to_dll`.  You _were_ able to build it locally, so appears not to be a question of whether EF 5.0 is supported...

Comment: My question is if other developers need to install the connector to *compile* solutions that use MySql with entity framework. I know it can *run* on machines without the connector installed.

Comment: @AnthonyBrien: I understand this, but it's possible that the .edmx generation tools require accessing the .dll from a global location, not your application path.  And you were able to compile it using EF 5.0 with this connector, which means it's not a conflict between EF and the .dll

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer:

Other machines without the MySQL Connector installed can actually compile the solution fine, without errors.

However, the edmx designer automatically pops up the error list with the *The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.* error. But it's not a build error!